# Better Breakpoints for Multi-Client Development

Tags: debugging, abap

My development system uses different clients for development and testing which I assume is a common practice. Unfortunately this introduces a rather annoying convenience issue when it comes to debugging. While breakpoints placed on the development system will stick to their code and move as lines are inserted or deleted, this is rather obviously not the case for breakpoints placed on the same code in another client.

Since the system has no knowledge of exactly how rows were changed between two versions, breakpoints placed in the testing client will remain at a particular line in the program. Any change to the code will therefore break the breakpoints. To resolve this I have to: open another program or screen then return to the program to refresh the code (where's the refresh button SAP?), find where the breakpoints have been moved to and remove them one-by-one (where's the batch remove breakpoints button SAP?) and then set new breakpoints at usually the exact same location.

This problem is becoming so frequent in my work that I sometimes spend more time moving breakpoints than I spend on the actual development. In some cases I just gave up and started coding in user breakpoints since those will at least remain in place. However, these come with their own drawbacks as they can't be removed in the debugger, making them useless when you are forced to stop at every breakpoint in a thousand-record loop.

My actual question is now whether there's a better approach or best practice when it comes to debugging in this scenario. I'm relatively new to ABAP programming so I hope that more experienced developers have alternatives or tricks that they use to speed this process up. Is there some better way to go about debugging and breaking code in a secondary client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a checkpoint group in transaction `SAAB`, and code the break-points to the checkpoint group.

**Syntax**

```
BREAK-POINT ID zyour_new_checkpoint_group.
```

This has the advantage that you can activate it for a set time, or a set of users etc.  However, I'm not sure that if you get stuck in a 1000-line loop that you will be able to just deactivate it & skip over the break-point.

It may be worthwhile to check first if you can deactivate the checkpoint group on the fly while the program is running before using this in anger.

Comment: This seems like it would be very useful for improved debugging of different sections of large programs. As you say it has some limitations but this should definitely help me out. Though I hope I'm never reduced to having to use it in anger. ;]

Answer (score 3):

The practice of having a development client and test client makes sense for client dependent objects, e.g. customizing. It ensures a reasonably stable environment for development testing. But it makes no sense for programs and other development objects since they are client independent. However, it is still important that all your client dependent development objects (e.g. standard texts and SapScripts)  originate from the development client so it is best to create all your objects there. But once you have done that and are on to testing and debugging there is no technical reason to not just change your program in the test client.

It might take some effort to convince the people responsible for development procedures of this practice since there always is a chance that objects get created in the wrong client which could lead to a mess when you want to release them. But with the scenario you describe in your question you should be able to plead your case.

Comment: I see your point and I'm definitely inclined to agree but sadly changing established practices will not be an option, despite its merits.